# Facebook share link and AIR StageWebView

Tags: facebook, air

I have an AIR app where the user could post on his/her FB wall by using the following link style:

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://www.someurl.com&p[images][0]=http://image.jpg&p[title]=Title&p[summary]=Summary%20Text`

It was working some time ago, however it seems to have stopped working now.

I URL encode the whole query string (maybe that's the problem?), and I've tested the resulting link works outside of AIR. I also have a link for Twitter, with another query string and it works with no problems. I've seen some other people having similar problems as well, but the solutions I've seen like using javascript:window.location haven't worked. Also tried to load a custom HTML through `loadString()` and afterwards redirect to the desired page, with no success either.

What do you suggest? Right now I'm using `navigateToUrl`, but would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why this is not working for you, but I'm sorry to inform you that the facebook share button has been deprecated and is no longer supported.

You can read about it in the documentation for the [Facebook Share](http://Facebook%20Share):

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

And in the documentation for the [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected

Since it's not supported anymore I'd accept the behavior of it to be unpredictable and maybe it's the reason why it stopped working for you.
I'm not a flash developer and don't have any solution for that, but you should stop using the deprecated method.

---

## Edit

My point is that since you are using a deprecated functionality, even if you manage to fix the current problem, you'll face others later on, so what's the point in spending time on finding/fixing the problem?

As for using like button in AIR, a simple google search for "adobe air facebook like" has resulted in this: [Creating a Facebook Like Button in Flash Professional for Adobe AIR](http://www.flashfood.net/index.php/2011/10/creating-a-facebook-like-button-in-flash-professional-for-adobe-air-1of2/).

Also, when posting/sharing something through facebook, their system scraps the url (unless they have a cached version) and so the image, title, description, etc can also come from the [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) tags in that page.

Comment: I know it is deprecated, but as I say, the same link works outside of my app with no problems. If I can make the user post a message in his wall, with a picture, a title, and a summary by using a direct single link using the new like APi, I'd be willing to know it, as I didn't find a way in the past, and that's why I used sharer.php.

Comment: Well, I don't want to register for an Application ID. So can I use the new API without one?

Comment: Oh, no, that you can not do (that I'm aware of). But it's really easy to create a facebook app, and as I already wrote, you'll have to face the instability of the deprecated share functionality which will probably cause you more problems. You can try to fight it, but you'll lose. If you want to use facebook you need to do it their way.